# GNUstep make dist

Tags: gnustep

Is there anyway to configure the name of the archive that is created with `make dist` ahead of time?  I have to recreate the file a lot.  Also how do you control the version of the archive as well.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

I found it a few days later. Just add this to the make file. :-)

```
PACKAGE_NAME = package-name
VERSION = 0.0.0
```